# OpenVPN reverse connection

Tags: firewall, openvpn

I'm struggling with my OpenVPN setup.

The `client` => `vpn-server`=> `internet` stuff is working,
but I can't get a handle on `server2` => `vpn-server` => `client`.

I've got the routing setup, and working, so I can `ping` from `server2` to `tun1` on `vpn-server`.

```
# ping 10.0.1.1
PING 10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.182 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.224 ms
```

But not any further.
A `traceroute` from `server2` also stops at `vpn-server`.

```
# traceroute -n 192.168.1.39
traceroute to 192.168.1.39 (192.168.1.39), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  x.y.z.137  0.176 ms  0.376 ms  0.526 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

**ip forward**: check

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

**VPN Server**: Firewall

```
echo "# Set rules for OpenVPN"
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -s -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 1194 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --destination-port 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -s x.y.z.128/26 -d 10.0.1.0/24 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s x.y.z.128/26 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

It's probably something with the `iptables` firewall, but I've been staring at it for so long, that I can't see what's mising.

Answer (score 0):

Although many reasons may exist, the client probably routes the response packages somewhere, which is *not* the VPN tunnel. I assume this, because

1. you wrote nothing about routing on the client,
2. you didn't use SNAT/DNAT/MASQUERADE between server2 and client.

One of above will be needed, and assuming that you don't use NAT, you need to push out a route entry to the client, which would 'yank' the route for the network server2 to the VPN tunnel.